# WorkManager freezing the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, worker, android-workmanager

I have a custom worker which has the job to fetch some contacts from an API, and then store these contacts in the contact list of the phone. This worker is still freezing the UI. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the Worker's doWork method:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {

    return try {


        makeStatusNotification("Saving Contacts", applicationContext, "WorkRequest Starting")


            //MAIN METHOD CALL

            if (!checkContactListEmpty()) {
                removeAllContacts()
            }
        connectAndGetApiData()


        val x = Data.Builder()
        Result.success(x.build())

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("NoWork","Unable to save image to Gallery $e")
        Result.failure()
    }

}
```

This is the connectAndGetApi method:

```
fun connectAndGetApiData() {

    val BASE_URL = "HTTP_URL"

    val res = Data.Builder()

    allNames = object : ArrayList<String>(){}
    allNumbers = object : ArrayList<String>(){}
    Log.d("entering", "connecting")
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
    val contactsApiService: RestApi? = retrofit?.create(RestApi::class.java)
    val call: Call<ContactList>? = contactsApiService?.getAllContactDetails()
    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<ContactList> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ContactList>,
            response: Response<ContactList>
        ) {
            Log.d("AllContacts",response.message())
            val contactList: ContactList = response.body()
            if(contactList!= null){
                Log.d("AllContacts", contactList.allContacts.size.toString())
                for(x in contactList.allContacts){
                    addContact(x.name,x.phoneNo)
                    Thread.sleep(50)
                } 

            }else{
                Log.d("AllContacts", "contacts null")
            }


        }
        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<ContactList>,
            throwable: Throwable
        ) {
            val TAG = "AllContacts"
            Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString())
        }
    })


}
```

The removeAllContacts() is standard function to remove all contacts

The Api results in a set of around 22000 contacts

Edited:

This is the addContact() method

```
 private fun addContact(name:String?, number: String?) {

    var finalName = ""
    val finalNumber = number



    if(name?.isEmpty() == true){
        val tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        val ts = tsLong.toString()
        finalName = "NoName$ts"
    }else{
        finalName = name.toString()
        finalName = finalName.substring(1,(finalName.length - 2))
    }

    val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()

    val rawContactID: Int = ops.size
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build()
    )
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, finalName)
            .build()
    )
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, finalNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build()

        //
    )
    try { // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction

        Log.d(
            "AddingContact", "Name: $finalName Number: $finalNumber"
        )
        applicationContext.contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
        Thread.sleep(50)
        Log.d("Contact Saved","Saved")
    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: OperationApplicationException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function hangs the UI connectAndGetApiData() or removeAllContacts()?

Comment: The connecAndGetApiData() method freezes the UI

Comment: Does your ```addContact``` function run on the background thread?

Comment: It seems like after you fetch a list of 22000 Contacts (on a Background thread using Retrofit enqueue) you are doing like iterating over 22000 items and perform some work in ```addContact``` function (I don't know what it does).

Comment: The addContact function is also defined in the worker class, and is called there, so yes the addContact function runs in the background

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this Retrofit call is done off of the MainThread, the callback is on the MainThread.

i.e. `call?.enqueue(object : Callback<ContactList> {`

anything you do in this callback will be on the UI Thread.

And you do this code:

```
          for(x in contactList.allContacts){
                addContact(x.name,x.phoneNo)
                Thread.sleep(50)
            }
```

Which is sleeping the UI thread for 50 milliseconds for every contact you have in that list. Which in the comments says has 22,000 items???

You'll need to use a background thread if you want to work with datasets that large.

---

A quick and dirty solution would be to do this:

Use Coroutines:

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2"
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2"
```

Change Retrofit to use Coroutines:

```
interface ContactsApiService {
    @GET("whateverYourEndPointIs")
    suspend fun getAllApiDetails(): Response<ContactList>
}
```

Run it all on a background thread:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        val response: Response<ContactList> = contactsApiService?.getAllContactDetails() 
        Log.d("AllContacts",response.message())
        val contactList: ContactList = response.body()
        if (contactList!= null) {
            Log.d("AllContacts", contactList.allContacts.size.toString())
            for(x in contactList.allContacts){
                addContact(x.name,x.phoneNo)
                delay(50)
            } 

        } else {
            Log.d("AllContacts", "contacts null")
        }

}
```

Comment: Sir, I have a question and my doubt, In the docs it says
" A task is defined using the Worker class. The doWork() method is run synchronously on a background thread provided by WorkManager."
doWork() already run on the background thread why we need our load-expensive work to run on a different background thread?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would still take a bet that the Callback for Retrofit is on the MainThread. Another quick check would be to use the `.call()` method on your API instead of `.enqueue(`.

Comment: I'm also confused here. In my previous project, I had also faced a similar problem when I try to query directly in ```doWrok()``` function it shows me error of "Query on Main Thread".

Comment: @Akshay If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers